# cocoa: a weird view line

Tags: cocoa

I implement a source list and a custom view in a split view as follow:

[image]

but the demo from apple doesn't have a line at the top of sourceview:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the outline view's enclosing scroll view. Set its "Border Type" to none (dotted lines, left-hand button on the control).